# Flutter: Crash upon running on IOS

Tags: ios, flutter

I'm trying to build and run my application on IOS. However, after successfully building the app, it crash upon launching an the error message that I received in my log was

```
(lldb) dyld[12223]: Library not loaded: @rpath/Flutter.framework/Flutter
  Referenced from: <8F813171-8323-390D-92E9-FE2434EDD1F5> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/AB427D6F-5D81-4DF8-9F90-C2F312AACB02/Runner.app/Runner
  Reason: tried: '/usr/lib/swift/Flutter.framework/Flutter' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/Flutter.framework/Flutter' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/Flutter.framework/Flutter' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/Flutter.framework/Flutter' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/AB427D6F-5D81-4DF8-9F90-C2F312AACB02/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/AB427D6F-5D81-4DF8-9F90-C2F312AACB02/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/AB427D6F-5D81-4DF8-9F90-C2F312AACB02/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/Flutter.framework/Flutter' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/Flutter.framework/Flutter' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/Flutter.framework/Flutter' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/Flutter.framework/Flutter' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/AB427D6F-5D81-4DF8-9F90-C2F312AACB02/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/AB427D6F-5D81-4DF8-9F90-C2F312AACB02/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/AB427D6F-5D81-4DF8-9F90-C2F312AACB02/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter' (no such file), '/System/Library/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
* thread #1, stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x00000001dd318ee4 dyld`__abort_with_payload + 8
dyld`:
->  0x1dd318ee4 <+8>:  b.lo   0x1dd318f00               ; <+36>
    0x1dd318ee8 <+12>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
    0x1dd318eec <+16>: mov    x29, sp
    0x1dd318ef0 <+20>: bl     0x1dd2bbea0               ; cerror_nocancel
Target 0: (Runner) stopped.
```

Anyone has any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

I've faced similar issue before, for me this happened due to some exceptions in initialization some packages in main() such as PackageInfo in line

```
await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
```

you have to move it after runApp() --> maybe before splash screen

this also may happen if you use firebase dynamic link you have to add these into info.plist

```
<key>FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains</key>
    <array>
        <string>https://domain.page.link</string>
    </array>
```

Comment: thank you for ur reply but I have none of those in my project. It seems to happen every time i run the command `flutter clean`